# Finding the limit of a function given the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Question]

Unsure how to go about this question. I have written it out as: $y(x)=f(x)+2$ since $y(0)=2$, but I am assuming that $f(0)=2$. This doesn't really help me though as it is said that the differential equation must not be solved.

Comment: It is an autonomous first order equation with a unique solution. At long times these can only blow up or go to an equilibrium point. To see which, check the sign of the derivative at the starting time and move in that direction from the starting position until you hit an equilibrium or have surpassed all equilibria.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(y)$ be the right hand side of the ODE. Note that $f(y) <0$ for $y \in (1,7)$. Note that $1$ is an equilibrium (stable, but that does not matter).
In particular, the solution must satisfy $y > 1$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Hence if we start at $y(0) = 2$ then $y$ will decrease and is bounded below
by $1$, hence has a limit $y^*$. We must have $y^* = 1$, otherwise we have $y'(x) \le - \delta$ for some $\delta>0$ for all $x\ge 0$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

For small values of $x, y'(x) < 0$  Which is going to make y(x) a decreasing function.  But as $y(x)$ approaches $1, y'(x)$ approaches $0.$  And what happens after that?  $y(x)$ becomes stationary.